# When fetching document from Firestore, am I also getting the collections inside this document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

And if so, how to get it? Because when doing the document reference, you can only access the fields of that document not collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When fetching document from Firestore, am I also getting the
>   collections inside this document?

No, when fetching a document, you will only get the fields of this document.

As explained in this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore), with Firestore, you can "create shallow queries to retrieve data at the document level without needing to retrieve the entire collection, or any nested subcollections". (Note that it is not the case with the Realtime database: if you fetch a given node, you'll get all the sub-nodes as well).

If you want to access the document's sub-collections, you have to [fetch them by using their IDs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection). 
If you are using one of the Client SDKs (i.e. "mobile/web client libraries"), there is no way to query for the sub-collections IDs of a document. It means that you need to know what are the sub-collections IDs for a given document in order to fetch them (you might save the IDs of these collections in a field of their parent document).

On the other hand, listing all sub-collections of a document is possible with the **server** client libraries, like the Java or Node.js libraries, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems to be too complicated for me, so I'll just rethink the database structure then.

Comment: Actually it might not be as complicated as it seems! If you know the IDs of your subcollections upfront (i.e. the data model is fixed) it is quite easy: you just have to issue several queries in parallel, for example by using `Promise.all()`.

Comment: It actually was a pricing concern, and as far as I can tell, even if you do that, you are going to get charged for other documents too. So changing the database structure is headache-less way for me to accomplish what I want. Although your attitude to answer this question made me happy. Thank you